# Kivy Popup dynamically change height

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following Kivy Option Popup

```
s ='''
<OptionPopup>:
    id: optionPopup
    size_hint : (None,None)
    width : min(0.95 * self.window.width, dp(500))
    title: "Option Title"
    height: content.height
    BoxLayout:
        id: content
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '5dp'
        height: contentButtons.height + cancelButton.height
        BoxLayout:
            id: contentButtons
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: '0dp'
            height : self.minimum_height

        SettingSpacer:
        Button:
            id:cancelButton
            size_hint_y : None
            height: '50dp'
            text: "Back"
            on_release: optionPopup._dismiss()


'''
Builder.load_string(s)
```

This Popup exists only once in my application and I will dynamically add Buttons to the `optionPopup.ids["contentButtons"]`. Meaning the `contentButton` layout `minimum_height` gets changed. How can I properly adjust the size of my parent Boxlayouts `content` and the PopUp windows?
The above `kv` options seem to do the right thing like binding `optionPopup.height` to `content.height`, but it does not work?

[image: The popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct kv settings are

```
s ='''
<OptionPopup>:
    id: optionPopup
    size_hint : (None,None)
    width : min(0.95 * self.window.width, dp(500))
    title: "Option Title"
    height: dp(content.height) + dp(80)
    BoxLayout:
        id: content
        size_hint : (1,None)
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '5dp'
        height: dp(content.minimum_height)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint : (1,None)
            id: contentButtons
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: '0dp'
            height : dp(self.minimum_height)

        SettingSpacer:
        Button:
            id:cancelButton
            size_hint_y : None
            height: '50dp'
            text: "Back"
            on_release: optionPopup._dismiss()


'''
Builder.load_string(s)

class OptionPopup(Popup): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.window= Window
        super(OptionPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = self.ids["content"]
        self.contentButtons = self.ids["contentButtons"]

    def _dismiss(self,*largs):
        self.dismiss()

    def open(self):
        super(OptionPopup,self).open()

    def _validate(self,instance):
        if self.optionCallBack is not None:
            self.optionCallBack(instance.optId)
        self.dismiss()

    def setOptions(self,options, callBack):
        self.optionCallBack = callBack
        print('OptionPopup::setOptions', options)
        print('OptionPopup::setOptionCallback: \n option changes go to: ',self.optionCallBack)
        self.contentButtons.clear_widgets()
        for optId,name in options.items():
            b = Button(text=name, size_hint_y=None, height='50dp')
            b.optId = optId
            b.bind(on_release=self._validate)
            self.contentButtons.add_widget(b)

    def setTitle(self,text):
        self.title = text
```

You can test this code by adding it to your application:

```
# Test the popup
o = OptionPopup()
o.setOptions({'opt1' : 'Options 1','opt2' : 'Options 2', 'opt3' : 'Options 3'})
o.open()
```